# Add new variable to Prestashop Cart object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop, cart

In Cart (I use 5 step cart) I've added radiobox "stock_action" and I need to send this value to the Cart object because based on the value I would like to add some extra costs to order.

In Cart Override I've added `$stock_action` variable:

```php
public $stock_action;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'cart',
        'primary' => 'id_cart',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_shop_group' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_shop' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_address_delivery' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_address_invoice' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_carrier' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_currency' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
            'id_customer' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_guest' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'stock_action' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
            'id_lang' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
            'recyclable' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
            'gift' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
            'gift_message' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage'),
            'mobile_theme' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
            'delivery_option' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'secure_key' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 32),
            'allow_seperated_package' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
            'date_add' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
            'date_upd' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
        ),
    );
```

But the value of the stock_action radio isn't sending after clicking the button to the next step in Cart.

Then I've tried to send that value using AJAX but I'm not sure how to send it correctly and catch it on the other side to assign to a Cart object. I've tried various combination of other functions in `cart-summary.js` and I came up with something like this:

```js
function setStockAction() {
  var val = $('input[name=stock_action]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
    url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'controller=cart'
    + '&ajax=true'
    + '&stock_action=' + val
    + '&token=' + static_token
    + '&allow_refresh=1',
    success: function(jsonData) {
      alert('ok!');
    }
  });
}
```

Am I on the right track or is there an easier way to do it in Prestashop?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you added this 'stock_action' field to the DB scheme?

Comment: Not yet, but does it matters if for now I only need to have this value in Controller to do some more stuff while order process didn't end?

Comment: Basically speaking you have to. Because in Debug mode you'll get an error kinda this  Unknown column 'stock_action' in 'field list' during adding a product to cart and other events. I would advise you to turn on Debug mode and check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'stock_action'` field to `cart` table in your DB. And then this property will be available in your cart class instance as well as other properties. If you don't you'll get an error in all cart-related events **`Unknown column 'stock_action' in 'field list'`**, to see it just turn on Dev mode in `config/defines.inc.php` set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` to true.

**UPD:**
To make your AJAX works follow next steps(in addition to previous)
1. Override/modify controllers/front/OrderController.php method initContent() and add a next code 
`if (Tools::isSubmit('ajax') && Tools::getValue('method') == 'updateStockAction') {
    $this->context->cart->stock_action = (int)Tools::getValue('stock_action');
    $this->context->cart->save();
}`
 just after
 `if (Tools::isSubmit('ajax') && Tools::getValue('method') == 'updateExtraCarrier') {
    ....
}` block
2. Go to your theme js folder and add to global.js your AJAX code

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="stock_action"]', function() {
    var val = $('input[name=stock_action]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
        url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'controller=order'
        + '&ajax=true'
        + '&stock_action=' + val
        + '&method=updateStockAction'
        + '&token=' + static_token
        + '&allow_refresh=1',
        success: function(jsonData) {
            alert('ok!');
        }
    });
});
```

3. Go to your theme template file shopping-cart.tpl and add somwhere your radio input

```
<input type="radio" name="stock_action" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="stock_action" value="0" />
```

I checked it out and it works! On all the next pages you will have the correct value of `stock_action` and it will be relevant until your cart exists or you change it to different

Comment: Without it I didn't get `unknown column...` error but I've added `stock_action` anyway and still value isn't passed on in Cart object I have 0 (and don't know why `string` since I set `int`), which is default value in DB `object(Cart)[17]
  public 'stock_action' => string '0' (length=1)`. Should it work with AJAX code which I have or without that code?

Comment: It shows you that value which is in your DB. What do you expect it to shows? Yes, you can use it with your ajax but you need to implement a handler in your front order controller OrderController.php. But I would advise you to modify/override this controller and adjust the method initContent() to your requirements in an appropriate step. Bytheway your ajax implementation also better instantiate here as with 'updateExtraCarrier' example

Comment: I've expected to have there value of checked radiobox, that is the whole point of this. Customer check one of two options in first step of a cart and I have his pick in Controller in step number 1 or at least in step number 2 and based on this I can do something